# Several FileOutputStreams at a time?

Tags: java, sql

The situation is that:

1. I have a csv file with records (usually 10k but up to 1m records)
2. I will process each record (very basic arithmetic with 5 basic select queries to the DB for every record)
3. Each record (now processed) will then be written to a file BUT not the same file every time. A record CAN be written to another file instead.

Basically I have 1 input file but several possible output files (around 1-100 possible output files).

The process itself is basic so I am focusing on how I should handle the records.

Which option is appropriate for this situation?

1. Store several `List` s that will represent per possible output file, and then write each List one by one in the end?
2. To avoid several very large `List`s, every after processing each record, I will immediately write it to its respective output file. But this will require that I have streams open at a time.

Please enlighten me on this. Thanks.

Comment: You could also use 1 but write out any list that has more than N elements: 1. read, 2.process, 3. add to the relevant list of records, 4. check each list (more than N elements -> open relevant output, write, close output and clear the list)

Comment: Thanks for the comment sir. But I meant that I'll only create a list for every record which needs another output file. So I won't be creating a List for every possible output file, just one for every ACTUAL output file. I hope I make sense.

Comment: Have you considered using Spring Batch? http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html

Comment: @BenoitWickramarachi, yes I once glanced at Spring Batch but did not really read all that much. I assumed that Spring Batch is somehow of an overkill? Correct me if I am wrong though.

Comment: No I don't think it's overkill, you basically need to perform a batch task so using a Framework built for that will help you a lot. Using Spring batch you could process the CSV file in parallel using a thread by chunk and also have an error management (if anything goes wrong you can either cancel the job (rollback any changes) or stop it and resume it later where it stopped). Just a few examples of what can be done…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second option is ok: create the file output streams on demand, and keep them open as long as it takes (track them in a `Map` for example).

The operating system may have a restriction on how many open file handles it allows, but those numbers are usually well beyond a couple hundreds of files.

**A third option:**
You could also just *append* to files, `FileOutputStream` allows that option in the constructor:

```
new FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)
```

This is less performant than keeping the `FileOutputStream`s open, but works as well.